# Highcharts with boost not rendering correctly at small intervals

Tags: javascript, boost, highcharts

When using Highcharts in combination with Highcharts's boost module, the graph is not rendered correclty when using small MS intervals for the xAxis.

Rendering 5000 records, with an interval of 10 ms, it looks like highcharts gets the average for a periode of time (i think)? On hovering the labels shows the correct location of the point line, not the straight line

[image]
I some how figured that the graph shows correctly at 4999 record:
[image]
Also using 100.000 record, but with a lower interval of 1000ms shows fine:
[image]

This problem only shows up when using the boost (which i MUST use because im working with millions of records). Without boost it works fine.

I could not figure out why its behaving like this.
Is this a bug of Highcharts? 
Am i missing a porpperty in my chartsettings?
How can i solve this problem?

See jsfiddle for the above example : http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lv41do/49/

My Settings:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {       
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    series: [{
        data: data,
    }]
});
```

Comment: Reading a bit about [boost](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module); *Perform value to pixel translations in the shader, rather than on the GPU. This may have adverse effects on some datasets **(especially those where floating point precision may be an issue, such as timestamps with small intervals)**.* Therefore I would say it is not a bug, but you could try playing with the boost options to make it behave as you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling the boost without the useGPUTranslation set to true.
E.g.:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
    // Enables boost without any other performance options
    boost: { },
    navigator: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {       
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
    },
    series: [{
        data: data,
    }]
});
```